# Optimize usage of collect()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have working code, but it takes 10 minutes for a task that my local computer can do in ~1 minute. So I think my code needs optimization and I think I am not using Spark, especially the SQL `limit()` and `collect()` methods, correctly.

I wand/need to move my problem to Spark (pyspark), because our old tools and computers cannot sensibly handle the sheer amount of files produced (and they apparently don't have the resources to handle some of the biggest files we generate).

I am looking at CSV files and for each file, i.e. experiment, i need to know which sensor was triggered first/last and when these events occured.

Reduced to the Spark relevant code I do

```
tgl = dataframe.filter("<this line is relevant>") \
        .select(\
            substring_index(col("Name"),"Sensor <Model> <Revision> ", -1)\
                .alias("Sensors"),\
            col("Timestamp").astype('bigint'))\
        .groupBy("Sensors").agg(min("Timestamp"),max("Timestamp"))

point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("min(Timestamp)", ascending=True).limit(2).collect()
[...]
point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("min(Timestamp)", ascending=False).limit(1).collect()
[...]
point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("max(Timetamp)", ascending=True).limit(1).collect()
[...]
point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("max(Timestamp)", ascending=False).limit(2).collect()
[...]
```

I did it this way because I read somewhere, that using `.limit()` is often the smarter choice b/c then not all data would be collected centrally, which can take quite  bit of time, memory and network capacity.

I test my code with a file, which is 2.5GB large, and about 3E7 lines long. When I look at the timeline of the processing, I get this:
[image: Timeline of exemplary test run]

The first interesting thing to note is that about every Spark task takes 1.1 minutes. The code shown above is responsible for the first 4 illustrated calls to `collect()`.

As all four calls share the same dataframe that originates from `filter().select().group().agg()` I would have thought the later three calls would be much faster than the first. Apparently Spark does not recognise this and starts from the original dataframe every time. How can I optimize this, so that the later three calls to `collect()` benefit from the intermediary results of the first call to `collect()`?

Comment: I would assume the 1.1 min Spark takes is for `orderBy().limit().collect()` tasks; it does not include the `filter().select().group().agg()`. Which would explain why it uniformly takes that much time. I am also not clear what you mean by the 'original dataframe' ? Do you mean `tgl` ?

Comment: @suj1th AFAIK Spark does lazy evaluation, which means it records what it has to do and only when you acutally want to have the results it does the processing. As the `tgl = `-statement does not fetch any results, Spark will not do any grouping, not aggregating.  As a result `tgl` is hardly more than a todo-list for Spark. When I call `collect()`, Spark will work through this todo list. I was hoping it would somehow keep the result of working through the `tgl`-todo-list, so that it doesn't have to do all the steps again, when I reuse `tgl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation about spark re-executing the DAG each time is correct, it arises from a very simple fact that spark is lazy and that spark has 2 types of operations:

1. transformations: select, filter, groupBy, orderBy, withColumn, etc which describe how Dataframe/Dataset will be transformed and contribute to the DAG
2. actions: write, collect, count, etc which cause execution of the DAG

Dataframes do not hold data, they are sort of virtual view that describe transformations of input data. One way to not cause re-execution of the DAG with each *collect* is to cache *tgl*

```
tgl = dataframe.filter("<this line is relevant>") \
    .select(\
        substring_index(col("Name"),"Sensor <Model> <Revision> ", -1)\
            .alias("Sensors"),\
        col("Timestamp").astype('bigint'))\
    .groupBy("Sensors").agg(min("Timestamp"),max("Timestamp"))

 tgl.persist()

 point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("min(Timestamp)", ascending=True).limit(2).collect()
 [...]
 point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("min(Timestamp)", ascending=False).limit(1).collect()
 [...]
 point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("max(Timetamp)", ascending=True).limit(1).collect()
 [...]
 point_in_time = tgl.orderBy("max(Timestamp)", ascending=False).limit(2).collect()
 [...]
```

It will prevent re-execution of the DAG, but there will be a price to for caching *tgl* to RAM and might negate benefits of the *limit* operation. How much is the impact, only experiment will show.

Alternatively if you define what kind of questions you want answered by you program, I could try and help you with writing specific query or program to answered in one go.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out last night my simply trying out stuff. I am using `cache()` to store tgl and i even do `spark.read.csv().cache()`. The result (according to the Spark application UI) is that my first call to `collect()` takes about 3 minutes, but the overall processing time for my 2.5GB test file drops to 3.5 minutes! The price is ~600MB RAM.  For now I modified my code to do `sqlContext.clearCache()` before loading the next file, although is is probably not a good solution for when we want to move to concurrent evaluation of data files.

Comment: cache() calls persist "def cache(): this.type = persist()". spark.read.csv().cache() will cache all of the columns in the CSV and will ignore column pruning, so if your csv has 20 columns and your logic uses just 5, than it will cache all 20 columns, thus waisting time and memory. I would recommend adding a select before cache/persist: spark.read.csv().select("col1", "col2").cache() and add columns as you need. If you know the schema of the csv then to speed things up you could add schema explicitly, thus skipping the step of inferring it.